# Project Based Learning (PBL) ideas for secondary math topics

Tags: secondary-education, functions, exponential

I have searched the web but not found too much that fits what I want. So, I thought I would try asking here.

I am looking for projects to use as PBL for grade 10 math. Specifically for the topics of:

1. Functions
2. Exponents/Roots

The projects ideally would be worked on by students in teams of 2-3, using about 8-12 hours of team time over a month.  The results derived would lend themselves to making a short presentation or PowerPoint.

Most things I find are too simplistic where the product is simply a calculation to complete a worksheet.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

The North Carolina School of Science and Mathematics has always done a great job of sharing projects.  If you go [here](https://www.ncssm.edu/residential-mathematics) you'll find links to various courses and the modules that they use in them.  I think the Algebra 2 and AFM courses are probably most relevant to you.

Comment: Thank you! This is a great resource for Algebra 2 and Calculus.